# I can not create 2 constructors which one is empty while other one taking parameters in Flutter/Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, constructor, named-constructor

The error I get is: All final variables must be initialized, but 'clicked' isn't.
Try adding an initializer for the field.

[image][image]

I was trying to pass the clicked data to another page by using BottomNavigationBar. I need to use constructors. I need 2 of them which is one of them has to be empty in my case. How can I do this?

Comment: Can you include code-snippet

Comment: All constructors must initialize all non-nullable, non-`late` members. Your `empty` constructor needs to use an initializer list to set an initial value for `clicked`.  For example: `KullaniciSayfasi.empty() : clicked = 0;`

Answer (score -1):

You are not using the empty constructor in `myHome.dart` but the one that needs an argument. So in `myHome.dart` line 16 should be:

`List<Widget> _screens = [MainHomeView(), KullaniciSayfasi.empty()];`